# Sort collection by discount

Tags: magento2, category, collection, discount, sorting

I want to **sort** my collection by **discount percentage** for my **sale category**, I don't know if it is possible in Magento

Comment: Can you please add some code that you have tried?

Comment: Why do I need code to do this? I thought it could be done using backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new attribute like `discount_per` or something like this. Using **Import** assign percentage values in this attribute.

Now in attribute description on **Storefront Properties** tab Set **"Used for Sorting in Product Listing"** to **"Yes"** and save it.

Open category where you want your sorting.

> Catalog -> Categories

Open your category, now open **"Display settings"** tab and set **"Discount Per"** in **"Default Product Listing Sort By"** dropdown (Discount per is the attribute that you have just created)

Now to add descending sorting, open tab **"Design"** and add this xml code here

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setDefaultDirection">
              <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
            </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

That would be all. Hope you find your solution

Comment: It was not working before. But after your edit on answer, it is working now. Thanks bro!